# TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable (spark._jvm)

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, java-package, geospark

I'm setting up [GeoSpark Python](https://datasystemslab.github.io/GeoSpark/tutorial/geospark-python/) and after installing all the pre-requisites, I'm running the very basic code examples to test it.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from geo_pyspark.register import GeoSparkRegistrator


spark = SparkSession.builder.\
        getOrCreate()

GeoSparkRegistrator.registerAll(spark)

df = spark.sql("""SELECT st_GeomFromWKT('POINT(6.0 52.0)') as geom""")

df.show()
```

I tried running it with `python3 basic.py` and `spark-submit basic.py`, both give me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jessica/Downloads/geo_pyspark/basic.py", line 8, in <module>
    GeoSparkRegistrator.registerAll(spark)
  File "/home/jessica/Downloads/geo_pyspark/geo_pyspark/register/geo_registrator.py", line 22, in registerAll
    cls.register(spark)
  File "/home/jessica/Downloads/geo_pyspark/geo_pyspark/register/geo_registrator.py", line 27, in register
    spark._jvm. \
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

I'm using Java 8, Python 3, Apache Spark 2.4, my `JAVA_HOME` is set correctly, I'm running Linux Mint 19. My `SPARK_HOME` is also set:

```
$ printenv SPARK_HOME
/home/jessica/spark/
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Jars for geoSpark are not correctly registered with your Spark Session. There's a few ways around this ranging from a tad inconvenient to pretty seamless. For example, if when you call spark-submit you specify:

`--jars jar1.jar,jar2.jar,jar3.jar`

then the problem will go away, you can also provide a similar command to `pyspark` if that's your poison.

If, like me, you don't really want to be doing this every time you boot (and setting this as a `.conf()` in Jupyter will get tiresome) then instead you can go into `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf` and set:

`spark-jars jar1.jar,jar2.jar,jar3.jar`

Which will then be loaded when you create a spark instance. If you've not used the conf file before it'll be there as `spark-defaults.conf.template`.

Of course, when I say jar1.jar.... What I really mean is something along the lines of:

`/jars/geo_wrapper_2.11-0.3.0.jar,/jars/geospark-1.2.0.jar,/jars/geospark-sql_2.3-1.2.0.jar,/jars/geospark-viz_2.3-1.2.0.jar`

but that's up to you to get the right ones from the geo_pyspark package.

**If you are using an EMR:**
You need to set your cluster config json to

```
[
  {
    "classification":"spark-defaults", 
    "properties":{
      "spark.jars": "/jars/geo_wrapper_2.11-0.3.0.jar,/jars/geospark-1.2.0.jar,/jars/geospark-sql_2.3-1.2.0.jar,/jars/geospark-viz_2.3-1.2.0.jar"
      }, 
    "configurations":[]
  }
]
```

and also get your jars to upload as part of your bootstrap. You can do this from Maven but I just threw them on an S3 bucket:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mkdir /jars
sudo aws s3 cp s3://geospark-test-ds/bootstrap/geo_wrapper_2.11-0.3.0.jar /jars/
sudo aws s3 cp s3://geospark-test-ds/bootstrap/geospark-1.2.0.jar /jars/
sudo aws s3 cp s3://geospark-test-ds/bootstrap/geospark-sql_2.3-1.2.0.jar /jars/
sudo aws s3 cp s3://geospark-test-ds/bootstrap/geospark-viz_2.3-1.2.0.jar /jars/
```

**If you are using an EMR Notebook**
You need a magic cell at the top of your notebook:

```
%%configure -f
{
"jars": [
        "s3://geospark-test-ds/bootstrap/geo_wrapper_2.11-0.3.0.jar",
        "s3://geospark-test-ds/bootstrap/geospark-1.2.0.jar",
        "s3://geospark-test-ds/bootstrap/geospark-sql_2.3-1.2.0.jar",
        "s3://geospark-test-ds/bootstrap/geospark-viz_2.3-1.2.0.jar"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! One addition here, if anyone is installing `geospark` as a package on the cluster, then they can also use the location `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geospark/jars/2_4/<JAR_FILE>` when specifying `spark.jars`, because that is the location used on EMR for both Master and Core nodes.

Comment: where can I download geo_wrapper.jar?

Comment: It's been a while but I thinkn we grabbed it from the geo_pyspark repo, just be sure to get the right version: https://github.com/Imbruced/geo_pyspark/tree/master/geo_pyspark/jars

Comment: And just in case you see the same problem in a Databricks notebook, you could install the missing JARs via the UI for the cluster configuration.

Comment: By the way, the error indicates that Python code was installed (thus the Python imports work) but not the JARs that are used by that Python code.

Answer (score 2):

I was seeing a similar kind of issue with SparkMeasure jars on Windows 10 machine

```
self.stagemetrics =
self.sc._jvm.ch.cern.sparkmeasure.StageMetrics(self.sparksession._jsparkSession)
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

So what I did was

1. Went to 'SPARK_HOME' via Pyspark shell, and installed the required jar

   bin/pyspark --packages ch.cern.sparkmeasure:spark-measure_2.12:0.16
2. Grabbed that jar ( `ch.cern.sparkmeasure_spark-measure_2.12-0.16.jar` ) and copied into the the Jars folder of 'SPARK_HOME'
3. Reran the script and now it worked without that above error.