# Unable to configure GeoSpark in Spark Session :

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, pyspark, geospark

I have been trying to configure geospark with Spark Session so that I can use spatial application on PySpark. I followed this [link](https://sedona.apache.org/archive/tutorial/geospark-sql-python/#multipoint) & tried to run the code which is mentioned as follows.

```
try:
     import pyspark
     from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
     from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext
except ImportError as e:
     raise ImportError('PySpark is not Configured')

print(f"PySpark Version : {pyspark.__version__}")

# Creating a Spark-Context
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf().setMaster('local[*]').set("spark.ui.port", "4050"))
# Spark Builder
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('GeoSparkDemo').config('spark.executor.memory', '5GB')\
    .getOrCreate()

from geospark.register import upload_jars
from geospark.register import GeoSparkRegistrator
upload_jars()
GeoSparkRegistrator.registerAll(spark)
```

When I run this file it gives me below error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\sourav\spark\code\geospark_demo.py", line 29, in 
> GeoSparkRegistrator.registerAll(spark)   File "C:\Users\user3.conda\envs\python37\lib\site-packages\geospark\register\geo_registrator.py",
> line 26, in registerAll
> cls.register(spark)   File "C:\Users\user3.conda\envs\python37\lib\site-packages\geospark\register\geo_registrator.py",
> line 31, in register
> return spark._jvm.GeoSparkSQLRegistrator.registerAll(spark._jsparkSession)
> TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable

I tried to manually add below jar files in spark jars folder

> •geospark-1.3.1.jar
> •geospark-sql_2.1-1.3.1.jar
> •geo_wrapper.jar

Now the earlier error is gone & new exception is throwing which is as follows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\sourav\spark\code\geospark_demo.py", line 29, in 
> GeoSparkRegistrator.registerAll(spark)   File "C:\Users\user3.conda\envs\python37\lib\site-packages\geospark\register\geo_registrator.py",
> line 26, in registerAll
> cls.register(spark)   File "C:\Users\user3.conda\envs\python37\lib\site-packages\geospark\register\geo_registrator.py",
> line 31, in register
> return spark._jvm.GeoSparkSQLRegistrator.registerAll(spark._jsparkSession)
> File
> "C:\Users\user3.conda\envs\python37\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py",
> line 1257, in **call**
> answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)   File "C:\sourav\spark\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py",
> line 63, in deco
> return f(*a, **kw)   File "C:\Users\user3.conda\envs\python37\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py",
> line 328, in get_return_value
> format(target_id, ".", name), value) py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
> z:org.datasyslab.geosparksql.utils.GeoSparkSQLRegistrator.registerAll.
> : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.SimpleFunctionRegistry.registerFunction(Ljava/lang/String;Lscala/Function1;)V
> at org.datasyslab.geosparksql.UDF.UdfRegistrator$$anonfun$registerAll$1.apply(UdfRegistrator.scala:29)
> at org.datasyslab.geosparksql.UDF.UdfRegistrator$$anonfun$registerAll$1.apply(UdfRegistrator.scala:29)
> at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
> at org.datasyslab.geosparksql.UDF.UdfRegistrator$.registerAll(UdfRegistrator.scala:29)
> at org.datasyslab.geosparksql.utils.GeoSparkSQLRegistrator$.registerAll(GeoSparkSQLRegistrator.scala:34)
> at org.datasyslab.geosparksql.utils.GeoSparkSQLRegistrator.registerAll(GeoSparkSQLRegistrator.scala)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
> at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58608226/typeerror-javapackage-object-is-not-callable-spark-jvm/60040120#60040120) which had similar issues, I even tried to add jars in spark config files with following code, but nothing seems to worked.

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath C:\sourav\spark\geosparkjar/*
```

I'm using Geospark 1.3.1, Java 8, Python 3.7, Apache Spark 2.4.7, my JAVA_HOME, SPARK_HOME is set correctly, I'm running on windows 10.

how can I fix this to proceed further? Any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

GeoSpark is currently available as Apache Sedona .

For a similar usecase, I followed the instructions :

pip install apache-sedona

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from sedona.utils.adapter import Adapter
from sedona.register import SedonaRegistrator
from sedona.utils import KryoSerializer, SedonaKryoRegistrator
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("spark://test:7077").appName("sedonatest").
    config("spark.serializer", KryoSerializer.getName). \
    config("spark.kryo.registrator", SedonaKryoRegistrator.getName). \
    config('spark.jars.packages',
           'org.apache.sedona:sedona-python-adapter-3.0_2.12:1.0.0-incubating,'
           'org.datasyslab:geotools-wrapper:geotools-24.0').getOrCreate()
SedonaRegistrator.registerAll(spark)

resultsDF = spark.sql("SELECT ST_PolygonFromText('-74.0428197,40.6867969,-74.0421975,40.6921336,-74.0508020,40.6912794,-74.0428197,40.6867969', ',') AS polygonshape")
```

P.S : Pass below 2 Jars during spark submit with --jars option :

- sedona-python-adapter-3.0_2.12-1.0.1-incubating.jar
- geotools-wrapper-geotools-24.0-sources.jar (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/datasyslab/geotools-wrapper/geotools-24.0/)

Comment: On colab at present this still throws the `TypeError` when calling `SedonaRegistrator.registerAll(spark)` (with SparkSession 3.1.2, Sedona 1.2.0).