# How to find the closest geospatial line to a geospatial point

Tags: pyspark, geospatial, palantir-foundry, geospark, apache-sedona

**Context**

I have 500,000+ road objects for all the roads in the state of Illinois that have a Geoshape property for a line. I additionally have a set of objects for points across the state.

**Need**

I would like to add to the backing dataset of the points object type a column for the ID of the closest road to each point. Most roads are within 50m of the points so this fact could help optimize whatever method is chosen.

**Previous attempts**

I tried using the [DataFrame.knn_join()](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/geospatial/vector_data_in_transforms/index.html#dataframeknn_join) method part of the geospatial-tools library native to Palantir. However, testing it shows that it apparently finding the closest line to a point doesn't work. Only finding the closest point to a point works. It also takes very long as well.

I also tried doing a [DataFrame.distance_join()](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/geospatial/vector_data_in_transforms/index.html#dataframedistance_join) however that returns all the objects within a distance and I only want the closest. I guess I could get all the roads within 50 m of the points and then calculate the distance between each of the results and the point and find the minimum but that seems like overkill and it will exclude roads more than 50m away.

I finally thought of using another library instead of geospatial-tools to do what I want. I asked ChatGPT how I could do this and it came up with part of this code that uses GeoSpark:

```py
from transforms.api import transform_df, Input, Output
from geospatial_tools import geospatial
from geospark.register import GeoSparkRegistrator
from geospark.core.spatialOperator import JoinQuery

@geospatial()
@transform_df(
    Output("ri.foundry.main.dataset.46a58ef8-732f-4bad-9b19-8e3aab9f5d30"),
    roads=Input("ri.foundry.main.dataset.32ea817c-1f13-4295-b0a1-345ca38e64d2"),
    points=Input("ri.foundry.main.dataset.e0530819-d744-49ac-9e39-91bacd41d199")
)
def compute(ctx, roads, points):

    GeoSparkRegistrator.registerAll(ctx.spark_session)

    joined_df = JoinQuery.SpatialJoinQuery(points, roads, True, False)

    return joined_df
```

However, when I ran this I got this error:

```
Java classpath reference error

A Python dependency you are using is attempting to reference a Java jar not in the classpath. Please check recently added Python dependencies, and add a dependency on the necessary Java packages (JARs) in the build.gradle file.
/transforms-python/src/myproject/datasets/nearest-road.py
    GeoSparkRegistrator.registerAll(ctx.spark_session)
```

I'm not sure how to solve this.

Let me know another solution or how to fix this code!

Comment: Can you confirm that you already completed the setup for geospatial transforms work as described here?  https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/geospatial/vector_data_in_transforms/index.html/#installation

Comment: @Ontologize I did. That's how I was able to test that those geospatial-tools methods.

Comment: I think ChatGPT gave you old code and you should be using `SedonaRegistrator` instead of `GeoSparkRegistrator`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65213369/unable-to-configure-geospark-in-spark-session. Also, if you want to use SedonaRegistrator etc., I believe you need to add this jar to your `build.gradle`: `condaJars "org.apache.sedona:sedona-spark-shaded-3.0_2.12:1.4.1"`

Comment: Tried that and got:

A DataFrame object does not have an attribute _jvm. Please check the spelling and/or the datatype of the object.
/transforms-python/src/myproject/datasets/nearest-road.py
    joined_df = JoinQuery.SpatialJoinQuery(points, roads, True, False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in code repositories with the caveat that there's no convenient way to take advantage of distributed processing because Apache Sedona's KNN only works for one point at a time and the other solutions use in-memory tools (e.g. geopandas). There was a [paper from 2021](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-78428-7_24) about implementing a KNN join query in Sedona, which would be distributed in the normal way Spark jobs can be, and the code appears to exist on a [fork of Sedona](https://github.com/acgtic211/incubator-sedona/commit/5d7a68c9e4bb435cc098c011df20a5e15d54e262).

If future readers are more familiar with geopandas or some other geospatial package, that's probably a better approach for them than the code below. My solution doesn't scale to massive data (but many shapefiles aren't actually that big on disk). I tested this code on the [Illinois Sinkholes shapefile](https://clearinghouse.isgs.illinois.edu/datasets/illinois-sinkhole-points) and the [Illinois Roads shapefile from TIGER](https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2022/PRISECROADS/).

Notes about this code:

- It assumes you upload all relevant shapefile files to a dataset (using the dataset like a folder for the .shp, .cpg, etc. files). One dataset for points and one for lines.
- It hard-codes column name assumptions that you will need to change
- It applies a Spark anti-pattern of looping through a collected dataframe
- The output column you care about -- the one with the roads info in it -- is a tab-delimited string of all the columns for that row in the roads dataset; it's named "nearest_road" in the output dataset.

```html
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output
from geospatial_tools import geospatial
from sedona.register.geo_registrator import SedonaRegistrator
from sedona.utils.adapter import Adapter
from sedona.core.formatMapper.shapefileParser import ShapefileReader
from sedona.core.spatialOperator import KNNQuery
from sedona.core.enums import IndexType
from shapely import wkt
import logging
from pyspark.sql import Row


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@geospatial()
@transform(
    output_df=Output("<output_path>"),
    points=Input("<input_points_shapefile_dataset>"),
    roads=Input("<input_lines_shapefile_dataset>"),
)
def compute(ctx, points, roads, output_df):
    SedonaRegistrator.registerAll(ctx.spark_session)
    roads_rdd = ShapefileReader.readToGeometryRDD(
        ctx.spark_session.sparkContext, roads.filesystem().hadoop_path
    )
    roads_rdd.analyze()
    points_rdd = ShapefileReader.readToGeometryRDD(
        ctx.spark_session.sparkContext, points.filesystem().hadoop_path
    )
    points_rdd.analyze()
    roads_rdd.buildIndex(IndexType.RTREE, False)
    points_df = Adapter.toDf(points_rdd, ctx.spark_session)
    k = 1
    using_index = True
    points_list = points_df.collect()  # noqa
    nearest_roads = []
    for point in points_list:
        try:
            nearest_road = (
                KNNQuery.SpatialKnnQuery(
                    roads_rdd, point.asDict()["geometry"], k, using_index
                )
                .pop()
                .getUserData()
            )
        except Exception as e:
            logger.warn(e)
            nearest_road = None
        p_dict = point.asDict()
        p_dict["nearest_road"] = nearest_road
        p_dict["geometry"] = wkt.dumps(p_dict["geometry"])
        nearest_roads.append(Row(**p_dict))
    points_nearest_df = ctx.spark_session.createDataFrame(nearest_roads)
    output_df.write_dataframe(points_nearest_df)
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for actually trying this! That takes quite the amount of time. I actually needed a way to use my current object datasets instead of shapefiles. Initially struggled to figure it out but then I got it! Here's my approach: https://gist.github.com/lectrician1/c3be4d9dc29701b3a014d3bafc67ce70

Also, I ended up going with a distance query. The knnquery approach after 20 mins with 300+ points and 500,000+ roads still did not complete.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you may need to write something custom to achieve your use case. What is your data scale? Can you write something locally and not run into memory issues or do you need the distributed compute?

Basically you want to create an [STR tree](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#str-packed-r-tree) on the lines, then for each point call the nearest neighbor method to get the closest line to each point. One downside of this is that all data will likely need to fit in memory on the driver. This is using the shapely python library, so you'll likely need to import this into your repo in all the normal ways.

Quick aside: `JoinQuery.SpatialJoinQuery(points, roads, True, False)` will always return false. The final parameter needs to be a predicate - see https://github.com/apache/sedona/blob/master/docs/tutorial/rdd.md#write-a-spatial-join-query