# Pyspark - Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o67.legacyInferArrayTypeFromFirstElement

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, py4j

`While creating a basic pyspark dataframe, its thowing this error, i am unable to find if its because of the software installation or version,

Java version 8
Spark 3.3.2
python 3.9.13

please let me know the issue if its because of the version and if its due to the environment as even simple codes are not working

````
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('sparkdf').getOrCreate()
data = [["java", "dbms", "python"], 
        ["OOPS", "SQL", "Machine Learning"]]
columns = ["Subject 1", "Subject 2", "Subject 3"]
dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
dataframe.show()```


Expecting a pyspark dataframe to be created but getting this error

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_22308\2222183590.py in <module>
      5   StructField('lastname', StringType(), True)
      6   ])
----> 7 df = spark.createDataFrame(emptyRDD,schema)
      8 #df.printSchema()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
   1274                 data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema
   1275             )
-> 1276         return self._create_dataframe(
   1277             data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema  # type: ignore[arg-type]
   1278         )

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py in _create_dataframe(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
   1318             rdd, struct = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
   1319         assert self._jvm is not None
-> 1320         jrdd = self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())
   1321         jdf = self._jsparkSession.applySchemaToPythonRDD(jrdd.rdd(), struct.json())
   1322         df = DataFrame(jdf, self)


TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable`
````

Comment: possibly related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58608226/typeerror-javapackage-object-is-not-callable-spark-jvm)?