# "TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable" in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, typeerror

Below are my version information:

```
    python = 3.11.5
    pyspark = 3.4.1
    
    java -version
    java version "21.0.1" 2023-10-17 LTS
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 21.0.1+12-LTS-29)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.1+12-LTS-29, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I am trying to run below code in jupyter notebook:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("practice").getOrCreate()

data_path  = "pathToFile\TelecomData.csv"
rdd = sc.textFile(data_path)

filteredRdd = rdd.filter(lambda pair: pair.split(",")[3] =='Y' and pair.split(",")[9] =='Y')

for rows in filteredRdd.collect():
    print(rows)
```

Below is the error im facing:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 10
      7 filteredRdd = rdd.filter(lambda pair: pair.split(",")[3] =='Y' and pair.split(",")[9] =='Y')
      9 # print(sc._jvm.functions)
---> 10 for rows in filteredRdd.collect():
     11     print(rows)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\spark_latest\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py:1814, in RDD.collect(self)
   1812 with SCCallSiteSync(self.context):
   1813     assert self.ctx._jvm is not None
-> 1814     sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
   1815 return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, self._jrdd_deserializer))

File ~\anaconda3\envs\spark_latest\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py:5441, in PipelinedRDD._jrdd(self)
   5438 else:
   5439     profiler = None
-> 5441 wrapped_func = _wrap_function(
   5442     self.ctx, self.func, self._prev_jrdd_deserializer, self._jrdd_deserializer, profiler
   5443 )
   5445 assert self.ctx._jvm is not None
   5446 python_rdd = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD(
   5447     self._prev_jrdd.rdd(), wrapped_func, self.preservesPartitioning, self.is_barrier
   5448 )

File ~\anaconda3\envs\spark_latest\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py:5243, in _wrap_function(sc, func, deserializer, serializer, profiler)
   5241 pickled_command, broadcast_vars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
   5242 assert sc._jvm is not None
-> 5243 return sc._jvm.SimplePythonFunction(
   5244     bytearray(pickled_command),
   5245     env,
   5246     includes,
   5247     sc.pythonExec,
   5248     sc.pythonVer,
   5249     broadcast_vars,
   5250     sc._javaAccumulator,
   5251 )

TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

So far I have checked spark installation in windows; there are some answers where adding jar path might solve error but in my case im not sure which jars to add.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58608226/typeerror-javapackage-object-is-not-callable-spark-jvm could be helpful

Comment: No, it's not. I am having the same problem with Python 3.10 and Spark 3.5.0.

Comment: i am still having same problem with jupyter. I used python 3.10 and spark 3.3.4 in pycharm it works perfectly.